# I want to reboot my Android tablet by a button

Tags: java, android, linux, permissions, system

after searching for a while to solve the above problem, i found out, that my knowledge is terrible low. ^^

I found many describtions of 'how to reboot your device' but i dont really get them, or it is just for rooted devices (which mine is not). Now my exact Question: How can i achieve Systempermissions for my app, WITHOUT rooting it and without writing an own firmware? A´detailed explanation would be very welcome, because i have low knowledge of Java-, android-coding and my linux knowledge is down to 0, too. Please help.

A second question,answered in a single word: If i got the system key (wich i need for the permission, as far as i understood) does my app run on other devices, too, or does it belong to this key then?

Comment: You simply can't without root.

Comment: absolutely no alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on this look you will get an idea .

[android-how to switch off my mobile through coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561427/android-how-to-switch-off-my-mobile-through-coding)

Hope this helps you .

Comment: thx for your answer, but for that my tablet needs to be rooted

Comment: it seems like without root you cannot ..

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860399/shut-down-android-device-programmatically

Comment: hmm.. thx, does the PM supports reboot or kinda time controlled start?

Comment: yeah it supports .. seems cannot switch off or reboot without root.

Comment: k thx... now i read that a root is nothing else but a superuser app, wich means it has to be possible to achieve these permissions, because the superuser apps have too.

Comment: Root isn't just as simple as installing the super user app. You usually have to make sure that the bootloader is unlocked, flash a custom recovery and then flash a SU binary file. The steps for this vary depending on Device and the carrier

Comment: @Boardy is correct. you need to connect your device with Pc and have to root it via Command Prompt

Comment: so it is not possible to create a commercial app, running on not rooted devices with system permissions, right?

Comment: what king of commercial apps you wanna create ?